# Deploy Silverlight Application : why need to add MIME Types

Tags: silverlight, mime-types

I have few question regarding Silverlight Deployment:

Is it a prerequisite  to add **MIME type** to deploy Silverlight Application?

if Yes, Why so, because the .XAP file can be handled by Static File Handler?

Is **MIME type** needed for Static File Handler ?

Comment: The MIME type is used by the client, not the server (if that's what you're asking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a IIS requirement.

As of IIS6 the default mime map of an IIS server does not contain a mapping of .* to "application/octet-stream".   The static file handler will to send the a resource to the client where the file extension does not have a mime mapping. This a part of an initiative to close down the attack surface of a web site.

Hence if you do not add the wildcard .* mapping or a specific mapping for .xap (which is preferable over .*) then a Xap file can not be delivered to the client.

**Side Note**

The Silverlight pulgin doesn't really care about what Content-Type header is set to.  In some cases where I have used a hosted service that neither supports .xap nor .* and even has the audacity to check that the contents of the file is what file extension says it is, I've renamed a xap to zip.  Pointing the source of the silverlight plugin at a zip works fine.